# Save image url to Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I have a database named 'mysqlproject' that contains two tables. One of the tables that i am interesting in is named markers and declared in database like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `markers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TitleEvent` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`Description` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
`lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`EventUserName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`PhotosEvent` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=73 ;
```

One of the columns is `PhotosEvent`that in there i want to save photo's url. So i capture a photo through a javascript file and i am sending it through ajax to a php file "camera.php"

The ajax sending procedure is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "camera.php",
        data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL
              }
        }).done(function( respond ) {
          // you will get back the temp file name
          // or "Unable to save this image."
          console.log(respond);
        });
```

So i am sending with method POST the image to the file "camera.php". In php file i am taking that image and saving it first in my "local server" in folder "EventImages". Ok that works .. 
But i want to save the url of the image in database in the field "PhotosEvent" only in raw where the active id is located..

Connecting with database :

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection) //Success $Connection with server returns 1
{
die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
else
{
//Connection with server established
}

// Try Connection with mysql Database
$select_db = mysql_select_db('mysqlproject');
if (!$select_db) //Success $Connection with Database returns 1
{
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
else
{
//Connection with Database established   
}
```

Save image to folder as .png (works) and attemp saving url to database (don't work):

```
if ( isset($_POST["imgBase64"]) && !empty($_POST["imgBase64"]) ) {    

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'EventImages/');

// get the dataURL
$dataURL = $_POST["imgBase64"];  

// the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
// that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
$parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
$data = $parts[1];  

// Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
$data = base64_decode($data);  

// create a temporary unique file name
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

// write the file to the upload directory
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

// return the temp file name (success)
// or return an error message just to frustrate the user (kidding!)
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';

 $results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (PhotosEvent) WHERE id ='".$_SESSION['id']."'VALUES('$dataURL')");
   }
```

My problem is saving the image url - path to database. How can i do this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you trying to insert a row or update an existing one?

Comment: updating an existing one..

Comment: UPDATE markers SET PhotosEvent = '$dataUrl' WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']

Comment: changed it...doesnt wok

Comment: No doesnt work... what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'EventImages/');
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);


$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';


$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM markers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$LastInsertID=$row['id'];
}
$results = mysql_query("UPDATE markers SET PhotosEvent='".$file."' WHERE id = '".$LastInsertID."'");
```

now it works ok.. I am fetcing the last known id that is in table Markers and i save the image's url that is stored in variable $file in the database!! I also save the image to folder EventImages as i did before!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an INSERT, then your `VALUES` is misplaced.

Do:

```
$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (PhotosEvent) VALUES ('$dataURL')...
```

Also make sure `session_start();` is loaded, since you are using sessions.

After seeing the comments in your question, then if

```
UPDATE markers SET PhotosEvent = '$dataUrl' WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']
```

or

```
UPDATE markers SET PhotosEvent = '$dataUrl' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'
```

did not work, then that could be the reason.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Using those error reporting methods will help find errors found in your code.

Comment: It does not work.. I tryed many compinations.. The ONLY line of code that creates a new id and inserts to that any data is : `$imageContentsEscaped = mysql_real_escape_string($success, $connection);` `mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (PhotosEvent) VALUES ('$imageContentsEscaped')", $connection);` but that inserts me value : 161078 . I dont know what that value is exactly. If i try this line of code with "UPDATE markers SET" at the begeening it does not work!

Comment: @monakons Use `var_dump($results);` right after your query, what does that yield?

Comment: @monakons Curious. Your form does contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: @monakons Plus, since we are dealing with files, these `dataURL = $_POST["imgBase64"];` should most likely be `dataURL = $_FILES["imgBase64"];`

Comment: It does not yield anything. I am not "staying" in camera.php to see something printed.. it just a php code for saving data. No i am not contain enctype="multipart/form-data" . Should i?

Comment: Yes, when dealing with files, it requires a valid enctype. Are you using a form with this also? @monakons